# Compute the marginal of X given the joint pdf of X, and Y.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose that the joint density function of the random variables $X,Y$ is given by the function
>
> $$
> f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}2-y},& x\in\mathbb R,y>0\\
> 0,& \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

I need to compute the marginal of X from the given joint pdf of X and Y.

Here I would integrate the joint pdf with respect to y from 0 to inf.

How am I supposed to separate variables in the exponential, to be able to pull any terms with X to the outside of the integral and then re-express the integral in terms of Phi?

My intuition tells me to complete the square, but I'm stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The marginal density of $X$ is given by

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left({-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}-y}\right)dy$$

Completing the square:

$$-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}-y=-\frac{(y-(x-1))^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$$

So, $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(y-(x-1))^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right)dy$$

Put $$u:= \frac{y-(x-1)}{\sqrt{2}}, dy =  \sqrt{2}du$$

and the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(1-x)/\sqrt{2}}^\infty \exp\left(-u^2 -x^2/2 +(x-1)^2/2\right)du$$

Pulling out constants:

$$\frac{\exp(-x^2/2+(x-1)^2/2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(1-x)/\sqrt{2}}^\infty \exp\left(-u^2 \right)du$$

and this last integral you can express in terms of the Error function $\Phi$ (the CDF of the normal distribution).